# C# Creating streamwriter files IF value is greater than or less than value?

Tags: c#

I was wondering if it was possible to write a new streamwrite output file when comparing two values. One of my values is in a `LabelBox` the other is in a `ListBox` and is populated by an input file. The purpose of it is suppose to be that this new value should change only when the LabelBox value is GREATER than the Listbox value. See the following code:

```
if (MaxRolls == 0)
{
    Random getMax = new Random();
    totalmoneyLabel.Text = "";
}
else if (RollCount >= MaxRolls)
{
    //
    if (runningTotal >= highscore)
    {
        StreamWriter outputFile;
        outputFile = File.CreateText("HighScore.txt");
        outputFile.WriteLine("New Highscore!!");
        outputFile.WriteLine(totalmoneyLabel.Text);
        outputFile.Close();
    }
    //

    MaxRolls = 25;
    RollCount = 0; 
    runningTotal = 0;
    totalmoneyLabel.Text = "$0.00";
    Show();
    MessageBox.Show("You lost!");

    return;
}
```

Comment: Anything is possible. What is your problem or question? What isn't working?

Comment: What's wrong with your code? what is the problem?

Comment: the program will not recognize the rule "runningTotal >= highscore in order to determine whether or not it needs to rewrite the output file or not...

Comment: you mean the condition not getting satisfied?

Comment: you can have a breakpoint and check the values of runningTotal and highscore, and see whether these are as ecpected. you have told when the LabelBox value is GREATER , But you have used >=(Greater than or equal)

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your code, trace the process, see what happens and check the values in RunTime, then you'll know why you don't get the result. The code has no problem, it is only the matter of values. That's it.